I encounter the following error: Cannot find module 'metro-core'
When I run the command npx expo start, I encounter the following error:
Cannot find module 'metro-core'

I found a solution:
1- "expo start --tunnel"
2- "npx expo-doctor"
3- "npx expo install --check"
It's working now!
